# Flask-Admin Cannot find reverse relation

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I already have an application using my SQLAlchemy model, and I'm now trying to add a flask admin website on top to manage some of the data in the DB. This model is already setup and working throughout the existing application so I know the relationships are configured correctly. 
In my DB the data_package table has a FK to the supplier table, and this has been added as a relationship. However, when I create a flask model view to allow editing of the data_package I'm receiving the error:

> Exception: Cannot find reverse relation for model

I've added a subset of the code below, there are a lot more columns and logic but this is the bare minimum I have to try and test a fix to the issue.The issue is happening because I am adding **inline_models = (Supplier,)** which I need as I want to have a select to allow the supplier to be changed for a data package.

The line of code throwing the exception is https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/form.py#L558. The reason for this is the relationship direction is defined as ONETOMANY, and there is a check to ensure the direction is MANYTOONE or MANYTOMANY

```
Base = declarative_base()


class Supplier(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'supplier'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)

class DataPackage(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'data_package'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)

    supplier_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('supplier.id'), index=True, nullable=False)
    supplier = relationship("Supplier", backref='packages')

class DataPackageAdminView(ModelViewOnly):
    form_columns = ['name', 'supplier']
    inline_models = (Supplier,)

def create_app():
    settings.configure_orm()

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return '<a href="/admin/">Click me to get to Admin!</a>'

    admin = Admin(app, name='Test Editor', template_mode='bootstrap3')
    admin.add_view(DataPackageAdminView(DataPackage, settings.Session, category='Data Sources'))

    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I think it related to this inline_models don't work for one-to-many · Issue #1405 · flask-admin/flask-admin
https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues/1405